# Async logger in Spring

Tags: spring

I have this question, i am just throwing it out there. I am implementing a small logging feature for my spring based REST API server for logging all requests coming in.
I am expecting 1000s of users to use this API so with a blocking i/o logger, it's going to slow down everything. I have two approaches to solve the problem:
1. Have a async logger using an in-memory arrylist. then use the spring scheduler to flush this out to a log file periodically.
2. Use JMS and send the logs to the queue. Let the queue handle the logging asynchronously.

Has anyone done this before with spring. Though i am for option 2, are there better ways of doing this? Need some expert advice. Thanks everyone !

More info - I think synchronous logging will be a bottle neck because this REST API is consumed by a front end RoR app. So one session of the user will definitely result in 100s of API calls occuring very frequently. I am logging the actual request along with the JSON sent in the POSTs.

Comment: Why not use an out-of-the-box solution? Would you want a carpenter to build his own hammer, forge his own nails, and sew his own toolbelt, or would you want him to concentrate on building the house using tools built by well-reputable companies utilizing years of existing R&D?

Comment: I doubt synchronous logging will prove to be a bottleneck. Usually if it's slowing things down, you should just reduce the amount of logging. That's why there are DEBUG, INFO, etc. levels.

Comment: Thanks guys. just updated the quesiton on why i think sync logging will be a bottleneck.

Comment: @jmort253, will you care to share the "out-of-the-box" solutions that are applicable here?

Comment: You can take a look at ZeroMQ. It will be better than JMS.
http://www.zeromq.org/

Comment: @SamarthBhargava - I just did a quick Google search and this was one of the first results. The article talks about asynchronous logging. http://java.sys-con.com/node/2123093. In fact, Ryan already posted it as an answer. Good luck! +1 as it's an interesting question.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I am trying two things out a. Spring with JMS beans and b. Spring with akka beans. I am also willing to give zeromq a go, but i'll have to code my own beans for that..which i dont mind doing. Will post my findings here in some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Has anyone done this before with spring.

Not so strangely, yes - [Asynchronous Logging Using Spring](http://java.sys-con.com/node/2123093)

The article mentions that if you don't want any log events to be lost, JMS would be the way to go - otherwise sticking to Async makes sense for high volume logging.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to build your own logger, I suggest you to take a look at [akka](http://akka.io), it is much easier than JMS to set up.

You can use it locally (use of all CPU cores of your local machine), or even with remote agents.

Comment: Yep. and looks like it has spring support too. Thanks.

Comment: @nice_ekito Do you have some learning resources on this topic?

Comment: Nope, nothing particular for logging, just the official doc: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/